Problem with Renewenvironment `marginfigure` provided by sidenotes package
I tried to renew the environment marginfigure provided by sidenotes package, however it failed to compile.
marginfigure is used to put a figure in the margin. The MWE example is to set/reset the value of a count before/after using the original marginfigure environ. (and also centering the figure):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidenotes}  

\newcount\mpUSE
\mpUSE=0\relax  

\NewCommandCopy{\Omarginfigure}{\marginfigure}
\NewCommandCopy{\OEmarginfigure}{\endmarginfigure}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{marginfigure}{o}%
{\mpUSE=1\relax\Omarginfigure\centering}{\OEmarginfigure[#1]\mpUSE=0\relax} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\meaning\endmarginfigure
For Test
%\begin{marginfigure}
%\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{test}
%\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}

Here the optional argument is taken by the ⟨end-code⟩ because it is set in this way in the original definition (See the following).
We don't need really insert a figure to find the error. The compiler shows an error with \NewCommandCopy{\OEmarginfigure}{\endmarginfigure}:
! LaTeX cmd Error: Error while copying command \endmarginfigure:
(cmd) Target command is not named \end<name>.

However, the \meaning\endmarginfigure can properly return the result:
macro:->\environment marginfigure end aux For Test

P.s., the following is the definition of marginfigure:
\newsavebox{\@sidenotes@marginfigurebox}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}{font=footnotesize}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{marginfigure} { o }
{
  \begin{lrbox}{\@sidenotes@marginfigurebox}
    \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}
      \captionsetup{type=figure,style=marginfigure}
}
{
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#1}{\usebox{\@sidenotes@marginfigurebox}}
}


Just locally setting \mpUSE to 1 is simpler:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\newcount\mpUSE

\AddToHook{env/marginfigure/begin}{\mpUSE=1\relax}

\begin{document}

For Test
\begin{marginfigure}
mpUSE=\the\mpUSE
\end{marginfigure}

mpUSE=\the\mpUSE

\end{document}


If you need also \centering, then you can use \NewEnvironmentCopy.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,right=3cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\newcount\mpUSE

\NewEnvironmentCopy{OEmarginfigure}{marginfigure}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{marginfigure}{o}{%
  \mpUSE=1\relax\OEmarginfigure[#1]\centering
}{\endOEmarginfigure}

\begin{document}

For Test
\begin{marginfigure}
mpUSE=\the\mpUSE
\end{marginfigure}

mpUSE=\the\mpUSE

\end{document}


(Pictures produced on A6 paper to make them smaller.)

Thank you, it looks simpler! I have two questions: For \AddToHook{env/marginfigure/begin}{\mpUSE=1\relax}, is it added BEFORE everything in the begin parts？; another question is: is the \NewEnvironmentCopy{OEmarginfigure}{marginfigure} similar to \NewCommandCopy{\OEmarginfigure}{\marginfigure}? Seems that they are used in the same place.

@XLeo The instruction \mpUSE=1\relax is added before everything in the begin part, but already in the scope of the environment; that's why you don't need to reset the counter when exiting the environment (because it's a TeX counter and it's being acted on locally). I don't understand the other part: you want to alias an environment, don't you? So use \NewEnvironmentCopy, so  \endmarginfigure is aliased to \endOEmarginfigure, which you can't do with \NewCommandCopy.

I think  I understand now. The \NewCommandCopy need alias twice (both to the end and to the begin); the \NewEnvironmentCopy only need to use the command once.

Retain the regular \end prefix for \end{<env>}:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sidenotes}

\newcounter{mpUSE}
%\setcounter{mpUSE}{0}% Default

\NewCommandCopy{\Omarginfigure}{\marginfigure}
\NewCommandCopy{\endOmarginfigure}{\endmarginfigure}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{marginfigure}{ o }{%
  \setcounter{mpUSE}{1}%
  \begin{Omarginfigure}[#1]
    \centering
}{%
  \end{Omarginfigure}
  \setcounter{mpUSE}{0}%
}

\begin{document}

For Test

\begin{marginfigure}
  test
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}

You can include the regular \begin{Omarginfigure}...\end{Omarginfigure} as part of your definition. Note that marginfigure requires an optional argument as part of \begin{marginfigure} (\begin{Omarginfigure} in your case).

It works. Thanks! Just one question: in the original definition of marginfigure: #1 is used in the <end code> part, why here cited in  <begin code> part?

@XLeo: It may be used in the <end code> part, but the arguments should be past as part of \begin{<env>}; that's just how it is.
